# Git status is not clean right after pulling from remote repo

Tags: git, remote-access, git-pull

I just pulled from bitbucket but it seems that my git status is not clean :
[image]

However when I check git diff, I have nothing... How is that possible ? My git status should be clean ...

Answer (score 0):

When you call `git diff` its for the actual changed files. So when you make a `git status` and you have some changed files you can see the diff of that files. When you pull something you get only new changes and you don't have changed files.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

If you need a special version of that file you have to specify the version number. You can see that in the documentation.

```
git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>…​]
```

Comment: ok but what about my git status why is it not clean after I just pulled ?

Comment: Sometimes when you have filemode on and autocrlf on files are changed automatically when you pull. You can set that in your .git/config

Comment: where is this .git folder ? I cant find it in my project

Comment: In your project root its hidden. Take a console and go to the folder.